# Converting String to Integer iOS + Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, int, swift2

I am accessing an API for weather and when I parse the JSON the result is a string. Since, the value I am accessing is a number, I want to convert it to an integer, but when the string has a decimal value, the string does not convert to an int. My code:

```
let UVIndex = swiftyJSON["current_observation"]["UV"].stringValue
let cityName = swiftyJSON["current_observation"]["display_location"]["full"].stringValue
if let UVIndexInt = Int(UVIndex) {
    print("Successfully converted! \(UVIndexInt)")
    self.UVIndexString = String(stringInterpolationSegment: UVIndex)
}
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.UVIndexButton.setTitle(self.UVIndexString, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    self.cityName.text = cityName
}
```

Comment: You want to get an `Int` also when the `String` has a decimal number? E.g. when you receive this String "1.2" what do you want to do?

Comment: Yes, when the string has a decimal I want to convert that into an int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to convert the `String` to `Double` and then to `Int`.

```
let text = "1.1"

if let textAsDouble = Double(text) {
    let textAsInt = Int(textAsDouble)
    print(textAsInt)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

An alternate solution without converting the the input string to a `Double` and then an `Int` would be to use an `NSNumberFormatter` to create an `NSNumber` from your string.  This way, you can get an `Int` or the fixed-width `Int32` type from your string:

```
let val = "1.1"

let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle

formatter.numberFromString(val)?.intValue // Int32
formatter.numberFromString(val)?.integerValue // Int
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative; in essence same technique as in appzYourLife answer, but using a closure:

```
let toInt : (String) -> (Int?) = { Double($0) == nil ? nil : Int(Double($0)!) }

var text = "1.1"
toInt(text)           // 1
text = "notANumber"
toInt(text)           // nil
```

Note that both this and the accepted solution will yield a runtime exception if, for some reason, `text` contains a number literal (in a string, naturally) which is larger than `Int.max` (on my 64 bit system: `9223372036854775807`). Possibly not likely, but if you want to take extra care (some crazy UV index?) you should take measures against this (e.g. truncating).